# Add text on video, text color should change dynamically with background color

Tags: java, graphics

I am working with Xuggler & Java.
I have extracted image frames from video & I can add text on Image frame and recreate Video by image frames.

```
Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D)Image.getGraphics();
g.drawString(data, x, y);
```

I want a way to change color of text according to background image pixel color so that text remain visible every  time.

Comment: +1 to your question but...  That's not typically how it's done.  Typically text is rendered in one color (say white) while simultaneously outlined with another color (say black).  Thanks to the outline you can typically read such text no matter the background.  Wouldn't that work in your case?

Answer (score 1):

Either use a semi-transparent color for the text, or put a semi-transparent background to it.

This is not exactly what you asked for, but it is workable, and 'the next best thing'.